# How to give a name to an object for debug purposes?

Tags: javascript, oop, debugging

I have this situation:

```
var Dog = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

var myDog = new Dog("Lucky");
myDog.bark();
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to give a name to an object and see it in the console when such errors are thrown:

```
Object [object Object] has no method 'bark'
```

I would love to see something like:

```
Object [Dog] has no method 'bark'
```

Is it by any means possible to do it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** As Cedric Reichenbach commented, this is a browser specific behavior.

Don't declare your *class* using an anonymous function.
Instead you should use a `function` declaration:

```
function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var myDog = new Dog("Lucky");
myDog.bark(); // TypeError: Object #<Dog> has no method 'bark'
```

Or using a named function:

```
var Dog = function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var myDog = new Dog("Lucky");
myDog.bark(); // TypeError: Object #<Dog> has no method 'bark'
```

Comment: This is very browser-specific and not really a correct answer. Technically, I guess both implementations should resolve to the same, which they seem to do in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Comment: Nice and simple! But what if I want to keep that notation for my classes? Is there any property that I can just update to reach the goal?

Comment: @Alessandro I don't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: I mean, what if I still want to define my classes with an anonymous function? Isn't it possible to set the class type as a property?
I imagine something like:
var Dog = function() {};
Dog.type = 'Dog';